# how to hide overflowing child element under view more button using jQuery as window size reduces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have placed 16 icons in a row. But as I reduce the window size, the overflowing icons collapse to the next row.

This is how it is now.
[[image: This is how it is now.]

This is how I want it to be.
[[image: This is how I want it to be.]

The overflowing icon should hide and a view all button should appear. On the click of the button, a modal box is popped.

I am not getting ideas of where to start with. Is there a way to get the overflowing child tag of a div in jQuery for a given window size.

Some hint or ideas will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your current code structure?

Answer (score 1):

Given we can use jQuery:

We need to calculate a couple of things, we execute the initial function on page load, and on the resize event.

First, we check the width of the container and the amount of the items, I multiply the amount of pixels each item takes (70) with the total amount of items to calculate the space they will take. If there are too many items `(container <= items)`, we unhide the view-more, and hide all items. Then we calculate how much space is left (`parseInt()`) minus 1, the view more item)

After that, we use the `.each()` function to unhide all items that fit, and we stop at the index we calculated in the `space` variable. The else statement undoes all the hiding, meaning there is enough space for all elements.

```js
function checkOverflow() {

 var containerWidth = $('.container').width()
 var itemLength = 70 * $('.item').length
 
 if(containerWidth <= itemLength) {
  $('.view-more').removeClass('hidden');
  $('.item').addClass('hidden');
  
  var space = parseInt(containerWidth / 70) - 1;
  
  $('.item').each(function(i, el) {

   if(i < space) {
    $(el).removeClass('hidden');
   }
  }) 
  
 }
 else {
  $('.view-more').addClass('hidden');
  $('.item').removeClass('hidden');
 }
}

checkOverflow();

$('.popup').hide().click(function() {
 $('.popup').hide();
})

$('.view-more').click(function() {
 $('.popup').show();
})

$(window).resize(function() {
 checkOverflow()
})
```

```css
.container {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #0FF;
 width: 100%;
}

.popup {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #00F;
 top: 20%;
 left: 5%;
 right: 5%;
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
 height: auto;
}

.item, .popup-item {
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #F00;
 margin: 10px;
}

.view-more {
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #F00;
 margin: 10px;
}

.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="view-more hidden">view more!</div>
</div>

<div class="popup">
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
 <div class="popup-item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries. Include the view more icon, and set its display to none.

When at certain width the design breaks. Set the display of some of the icons to none and the display of the view more icon to inline-block.

You haven't shared the code, hence I can't come up with other solutions.

Comment: That's not really flexible to remove items.

Comment: I assumed he has a given number of items. In that case, it will work.Of course, there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <div><span class="more">Show more</span> //inside span you can use icon 

    /// Content here
    </div>

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.more').click(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Show more') {
            $(this).text('Hide');
            $(this).parent().css('height', '100%'); // 100% == span parent div actual height
        } else {
            $(this).text('Show more');
            $(this).parent().css('height', '90px'); //90px == div visible height
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hope this will help

Comment: It won't, since this absolutely isn't responsive.

Comment: add class to div and make it responsive.

Comment: https://www.printshoppy.com/business-cards check this page bottom Show More button and it's a proper responsive.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's actual question.. not to mention unmaintainable at best.

Answer (score 0):

Use media query and make it look like this (*view this on full screen*):

```js
$('.open-popup').on('click', function() {
  $('.popup').css('display', 'block');
  $('.fade-bg').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.close-popup').on('click', function() {
  $('.popup').css('display', 'none');
  $('.fade-bg').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.menu-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.menu-holder .menu-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu-holder .menu-item img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.menu-holder .menu-item .text {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 680px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}
.popup .menu-holder {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.popup .menu-item {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.fade-bg {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.close-popup {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-holder">
 <div class="menu-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">Icon</span>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">Icon</span>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">Icon</span>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">Icon</span>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">Icon</span>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">Icon</span>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">Icon</span>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-item">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">Icon</span>
 </div>
 <div class="menu-item open-popup">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
  <span class="text">View More</span>
 </div>
</div>


<div class="popup">
 <div class="menu-holder">
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-item">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" />
   <span class="text">Icon</span>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="close-popup">&times; Close</div>
</div>

<div class="fade-bg"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Roberrrt Can I know why?

Comment: This doesn't hide the overflowing icons, ergo: doesn't work on small screens